# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views exception and standard solution

Tags: android, multithreading, gridview, thread-safety

At the beginning there is no local data, and the gridview should be empty, after that it start getting data using okhttp, if it works, then update the gridview content.

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blog_list, container, false);
    gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    try {
        get_data(Constant.get_cat_list);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return v;
}


  public void get_data(String url) throws Exception {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                Log.d("test1", response.body().string());

                gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity()));

            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is the `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views exception`, I found the solution , however, I afraid can I achieve the same result through re-ordering the code instead of adding the below code to everywhere when I do the update task after download the data?

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {

//stuff that updates ui

    }
});
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Wrap your call in an AsyncTask and alter the view in onPostExecuteMethod().

Comment: yes where should I  update after getting data ?thanks

Comment: use Rx Android instead of AsyncTask, its way better.

Comment: In your onCreateMethod() call the AsyncTask. You know what an AsyncTask is and how it works and needs to be implemented? Override the onPostExecute() method and there you can update your gridview.

Comment: so okhttp is not async already, I need to use the anynctask to include the code?thx

Comment: I see just realize the onresponse is background thread instead of ui thread thanks